# Use .add() Method on ResponseList from twitter4j?

Tags: java, twitter4j

*twitter4j-examples* gives us an example how to handle the response from *twitter.lookupUsers()*:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.twitter4j/twitter4j-examples/2.2.0/twitter4j/examples/user/LookupUsers.java

I wonder how to add next bulk from *twitter.lookupUsers()* to a common ResponseList (i.e. this is required because of limits if we must process >5000 userIds).

A try with:

```
users.add(next_user);
```

generates a NullPointerException :(

Any idea how to put the additional User objects in the ResponseList? Another solutions are welcome, too :)
TIA

Comment: you get  a NPE because the users object is null, how are you implementing that??

Answer (score 0):

@"ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ":  thx! That opened my eyes! Indeed my User was null.

So now, to complete the task: how to initialise a *ResponseList* properly?

Normaly for one-time job there is:

```
ResponseList<User> users = twitter.lookupUsers(userScreenNames1);
```

but i need to use the .add method, so i must initialize the List before, but how? Pseudo code:

```
    ResponseList<User> users = null; // <--- HERE

    for (User user : twitter.lookupUsers(userScreenNames1)) {
        System.out.println("1. List: user=" + user.toString());
        users.add(user);
    }

    for (User user : twitter.lookupUsers(userScreenNames2)) {
        System.out.println("2. List: user=" + user.toString());
        users.add(user);
    }
```

THX! :)